# Getting list item position()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get the position of a list item but I'm getting 0 in both cases...

```
// html
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="itm1">ITEM ONE</li>
    <li id="itm2">ITEM TWO</li>
</ul>

// css
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:5em;
    left:1em;
}

// JS
clickMenuItem = function(t) {
    var pos = $('#' + t).position();
    var y = pos.top;
    console.log('y : '+y)
}

clickMenuItem('itm1');
clickMenuItem('itm2');
```

How do properly retrieve the position in this case?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/WbxCA/

Comment: I guess in the context of the example it's ok... not as much in real application. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with jquery at the `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code */ });`:

```
$("li").click(function(e){
    var pos = $(this).position();
});
```

just log this variable then..

Comment: ok, logging it seems to do the trick, I just have to weave it in the real code somewhere. Thank you